# Nested grouping? (Error 1111. Invalid use of group function)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

### Background info & context

I have a table that keeps track of what time a lead (`rid`) is sent to a call center from a dealer's CRM, as well as if and when that lead has been called yet.

`sent` and `called` are unix timestamps.

| id | rid | sent | called | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1396887391 | 1615090216 | called |
| 2 | 4 | 1397591473 | null | waiting |

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cc_queue` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `sent` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `called` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('waiting','called') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rid` (`rid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `sent` (`sent`),
  KEY `called` (`called`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=81933 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This query determines the last time each lead (`rid`) is sent to the call center (`actual_sent`), the total number of times it was called (`count`), and the last time it was called (`last_called`).

```sql
SELECT rid,  
  COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'called' THEN rid END), 0) AS count, 
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'called' THEN called END), 0) AS last_called,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN sent != called THEN sent END), 0) AS actual_sent
FROM myfreshp_crm.cc_queue
GROUP BY rid
```

### The problem I'm having

Now I need to determine the the total number of times each lead was called ***after*** `actual_sent`.

Here's what I most recently tried:

```sql
COALESCE(COUNT(
   CASE WHEN status = 'called' 
   and called > COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN sent != called THEN sent END), 0) 
THEN rid END), 0) AS net_count,
```

I got Error 1111. Invalid use of group function.

How can I get this info? Do I need to do a join on the same table or something?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? You can do it using window functions. Otherwise you need to use a subquery for the first level of aggregation.

Comment: Nope. Mysql Version.. 5.6 :/

Comment: The linked quesiton shows how to do it with nested queries.

Comment: @Barmar - That's not the same question at all. `called` is not part of the aggregate.

Comment: I've reopened, you can put your solution in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use 2 subqueries, one to select the aggregate stuff from and one to get the count from using the results of the aggregate query. Probably not the most ideal solution, but it worked for me.

```sql
select 
    z.rid,
    z.count,
    z.last_called,
    z.actual_sent,
    (select 
        COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'called' and called > z.actual_sent THEN rid END), 0)
        FROM myfreshp_crm.cc_queue
        where rid = z.rid
    ) AS net_count
from (
    SELECT rid,  
      COALESCE(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'called' THEN rid END), 0) AS count, 
      COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'called' THEN called END), 0) AS last_called,
      COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN sent != called THEN sent END), 0) AS actual_sent
    FROM myfreshp_crm.cc_queue
    GROUP BY rid
) z
```